# Non singular curve with four variables

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, curves, algebraic-curves

How can I check if a curve with four variables (in $\mathbb{P}^3$) is non singular?
For example, the curve over $\mathbb{F}_2$ given by

\begin{cases} y^2z+z^2y+xzt+yzt+xt^2+yt^2= 0 \\ 
    x^2+yz+xt+yt+zt+t^2=0.
\end{cases}

In two variables (affine case) and in three variables, I can use the Jacobi Criterion, but I don't know how I can verify in my case.
I think I have to look at the Jacobian matrix $$J=\left( \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j} \right)_{1 \le i \le 2 \\ 1 \le j \le 4},$$

(where $f_1 = y^2z+z^2y+xzt+yzt+xt^2+yt^2$, $f_2 = x^2+yz+xt+yt+zt+t^2=0$ and $x_1=x$, $x_2=y$, $x_3=z$, $x_4=t$) and verify that J applied in $P$ has rank $n-1$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your thought is correct - you should do that.

Comment: I am confused still. Because the rank of $J$ is at most $2$ and my confusing is: if $V(f_1, f_2)$ is a curve (I didn't verify this), then $dim V=1$ so that J(P) has rank $4-1=3$ for a non singular point $P$... What is wrong?

Comment: $n$ is the dimension of the projective space you're embedded in, which in this case is $3$, not $4$ as you seem to think.

Comment: Thank you! Now I noticed where I was wrong.